# Snackbar view in android getting affected because of background image

Tags: java, android, view, android-snackbar

Can the snack bar in my Android app have a different view than the view of the ACtivity? My activity resides in a layout which has an image background. When i display the snack bar in that activity i am hardly able to read anything as the Snack bar seems to acquire the layout background. Is there any way by which i can have snackbar with a black background in an activity whose layout has an image background?

```
if (!email.matches(emailPattern))
        {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(view, "Invalid email address.Please enter a valid email address" , Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

            snackbar.show();

            return;
        }
```

Comment: `snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#hexcolor"))` Try this out.

Comment: @AlphaQ.. I tried the following code:Snackbar snackbar1 =null;
            snackbar1.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));
            snackbar1.setText("Invalid email address.Please enter a valid email address");
            snackbar1.show(); But the app crashed

Comment: @AlphaQ..It worked now..I added snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3")); to the code i posted in the question.It worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding the modified code here:

```
if (!email.matches(emailPattern))
{
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,
 "Invalid email address.Please enter a valid email address" , Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
 snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#hexcolor"));
 snackbar.show();
 return;
}
```

Like you mentioned in the comments section, your app crashes because of a *NullPointerException* generated by the `snackbar` variable. You have to initialize it before setting the properties.